# How can I get ACLs to work?

Tags: ubuntu, access-control-list

I have these ACLs for a directory:

```
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r--
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:root:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r--
```

I am logged in as root and type:

```
touch foo
```

Then an ls -l would give `-rw-rw-r--+` for foo.

Why? (Where's the 'x')

Answer (score 3):

ACL's are limited to what the group permissions allow.

You can see the effective ACL using the command `getfacl dir-or-file`

If you want to change the default group rights for newly created files, then you should look at `umask` instead or as well.

You set the default system-wide umask in `/etc/profile`

See more:

- Here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/umask.1posix.html
- Here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask
- Here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html

.. to learn more about umask.